# Vertical navbar using Bootstrap and angular

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am trying to implement a vertical navbar in my page. This page will be rendered by Angular. 
Somehow I am not able to get this to working. not sure what I am missing here.

Clicking on different tabs does not display their respective pages.

Any clues anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated.

here is a plnkr I have created for troubleshooting:
    http://plnkr.co/edit/dzfv8VMWCJk8cywgy5mm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dynamically set the classes of elements under `nav-tabs` and `tab-content`.  The easiest way to accomplish this is to use `ng-class` attribute that calls a function in your controller to return appropriate class for each tab.  To set the active tab, use `ng-click` on the `nav-tabs`.

Here is a working version in Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UBBq7V8mdyqllBHdwegY

Comment: this is not a vertical navbar... this are "vertical tabs"... which it's not the same... I wonder if there is a way to implement a vertical navbar...